# Closing application after X mins of inactivity in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, timer

I have an application that I need to close after it is inactive or not used. I have written the below code and am getting

> System.InvalidOperationException in windowsBase.dll

Do you have any idea how I can get this done? I need the application not to "freeze" using some of the threading timers.

```
Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    Dim aTimer As System.Timers.Timer
    aTimer = New System.Timers.Timer()
    aTimer.Interval = 9000

    ' Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.  
    AddHandler aTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent

    ' Start the timer
    aTimer.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub OnTimedEvent(source As Object, e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
Dim app as Application

Private Sub OnTimedEvent(source As Object, e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
     app.Exit()
End Sub
```

That seems to have worked for me.

Here is my full code on a blank form I made to test your issue. I get the smae exception you get trying to use Me.Close() but my Application.Exit() and app.Exit() work without a problem.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim app As Application

Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim aTimer As System.Timers.Timer
    aTimer = New System.Timers.Timer()
    aTimer.Interval = 5000

    ' Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.  
    AddHandler aTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent

    ' Start the timer
    aTimer.Enabled = True
End Sub



Private Sub OnTimedEvent(source As Object, e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)

    'Environment.Exit(0) - closes without a problem

    'Application.Exit() - closes without a problem

    'closes without a problem.
    app.Exit()


    'Me.Close() - System.InvalidOperationException
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: this is showing "reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference"

Comment: Try my edit. Let me know if your are still having problems. As it appears it is an issue with object access.

Comment: Now it is underlining "app.exit" red and erroring: Public event exit as exiteventhandler is an event and cannot be called directly. use a raiseEvent statement to raise an event.-    Thanks for oyur help

Comment: Is MainWindow your mainform (as it sounds like it is) and are there any other forms open at the time you wish to terminate the application?

Comment: yes mainwindow is the main form, no others open. that is correct.

Comment: You can try : Environment.Exit(0)

Comment: Do you think that is due to the Visual Studios 2015? or the netframework? or?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015 so it is unlikely. Its an issue that would require someone to know more about your install and what else you are doing inside your application. For some reason it won't let you directly call Exit() within the Application class. If you are really curious on getting it figured out I suggest the first thing you do is make a new solution with my code and see if it works. Then you know that it is something unique to your solution or what you are trying to do. If it still doesn't work you would need to look deeper into your install and dlls possibly.